# How to post Instagram photo to Twitter as a photo

Tags: twitter, photos, instagram

Before Facebook acquired Instagram, you can view IG photos on Twitter as a native photo if you have them linked. Now, only the description and IG link of that photo will be tweeted. What do you do to post the IG photo as a photo on Twitter, and not just its description and link?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Solution: IFTTT (If This Then That)

1. Sign up for an account in [IFTTT](https://ifttt.com).
2. Go to this recipe: [Post your Instagram photos as native Twitter photos](https://ifttt.com/recipes/68915-post-your-instagram-photos-as-native-twitter-photos)
3. Link your Twitter and Instagram accounts.
4. Click Add.
5. Done!

Here's what it will look like on Twitter. The ift.tt link redirects to the Instagram link of the photo.

[image]